# Second AJAX call to one div element not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div element #profInfo and two buttons #profEdit and #profEditDone. The first AJAX call is working, the second one isn't. Can't seem to pinpoint the problem.

```
jQuery(
    function() {
        $("#profEdit").click(function() {
            $("#profInfo").load("profile_edit_info.php");
        });
    },
    function() {
        $("#profEditDone").click(function() {
            $("#profInfo").load("profile_info.php");
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: how is it not working? there is no file profile_info.php ? the propInfo is not updated?

Comment: $(handler,handler) is not valid syntax. Pseudo ready event accepts only one argument

Comment: @florin There is a profile_info.php. @A what is the correct syntax? So use document.ready?

Comment: @user3786546 e.g: `$(function(){$("#profEdit").click(...); $("#profEditDone").click(...);});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery function takes one function to execute on the document ready event, not two:

```
jQuery(
    function() {
        $("#profEdit").click(function() {
            $("#profInfo").load("profile_edit_info.php");
        });
        $("#profEditDone").click(function() {
            $("#profInfo").load("profile_info.php");
        });
    }
);
```

Chances are it was simply ignoring the second function because it doesn't expect a second function parameter after executing the first one.  Note also that if these `#profEdit` and `#profEditDone` elements are in any way replaced as a result of these AJAX operations then your click bindings will be lost.  If that's also happening you'll want to use `.on()` instead and bind to a common parent element:

```
jQuery(
    function() {
        $(document).on("click", "#profEdit", function() {
            $("#profInfo").load("profile_edit_info.php");
        });
        $(document).on("click", "#profEditDone", function() {
            $("#profInfo").load("profile_info.php");
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Just curious though, why do my questions keep getting downvoted?

Comment: @user3786546: I don't know, I didn't downvote this one.  Don't take it personally though, people vote for all sorts of reasons not all of which I would consider proper reasons.